# .NET Core HTTP POST with model missing parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a Class named Server

```
public class Server
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public string ServerUrl { get; set; }
    public int ServerIndex { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string SID { get; set; }
}
```

In my server controller, I have  HTTP post function

```
[HttpPost]
public Server Add(Server server)
{
    return _serverService.Add(server);
}
```

When my JSON is as follows (value of SID is missing), it is not hitting the above function.

```
{
  "serverIndex": 0,
  "serverName": "string",
  "serverUrl": "string",
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string"
}
```

If I create a new model called SeverPostModel, with out SID and use it in controller it works.
Is there a way to use the same existing model. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean? You should get some sort of response from the Post that tells you what went wrong.

Comment: No response. If I keep a debugger at the function, it is not reaching there. If I include SID in JSON, the debugger is hit.

Comment: What http status code is being returned? _"I don't know" is not acceptable - check it in Chrome Developer Tools._

Comment: It is good practice to use different models for the front end and keep your Entity classes separate. You shouldn't try to accommodate Entity classes to fit the UI needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
    public Server Add([FromBody]Server server)
    {
        return _serverService.Add(server);
    }
```

Have you tried using FromBody?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the issue is related to the method you are using to post data to the action method. And, please check whether the request URL is correct or not? It is better to post the related code to reproduce the problem.

Based on your code and description, I create a sample on my side, and use the Submit Form and JQuery method to transfer data to the action method, both of them works well on my side.

Use the Submit Form method to transfer data:

Code in the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Add()
    {   
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Server Add(Server server)
    {
        return server;
    }
```

Code in the View:

```
@model Test.Models.Server

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Add">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServerName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ServerName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ServerName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServerUrl" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ServerUrl" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ServerUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ServerIndex" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ServerIndex" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ServerIndex" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Username" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SID" class="form-control" /> 
                <span asp-validation-for="SID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

After clicking the Submit button, it will submit the form data to the action method (please check your code to make sure the action attribute value is correct and the element's name value is correct).

the screenshot as below (if remove the SID element, it also transfers data to the Post action method):

[image]

If use JQuery code to submit the form data, code like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () { 
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent the submit button default event.

            var server = {}; //create a object and get the entered data
            server.ServerName = $("input[name='ServerName']").val();
            server.ServerUrl = $("input[name='ServerUrl']").val();
            server.ServerIndex = $("input[name='ServerIndex']").val();
            server.Username = $("input[name='Username']").val();
            server.Password = $("input[name='Password']").val();
            server.SID = $("input[name='SID']").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Add",
                data: server, 
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

The result like this (If removing the SID element, it still works well):

[image]

Comment: In the above scenario what happens, when the SID is missing in the form? Also, my solution is a .NET Core API, so I am using Swagger, Postman and Curl to hit the controller endpoint.

Comment: By using the above code, if the form doesn't contain the SID or the SID is missing, the code still works well. I also create a dotnet core API application and using Postman to send the request, the result like this: [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjdXg.png) and  [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDGML.png). I also try to use your JSON string, it also works well on my side, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amn6U.png). So, please re-check it. If still not working, I suggest you try to create a new web API application to test it. Otherwise, you could create a view Model as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you loss something.

1. If you are using `https` not `http`, your HttpPost client should disable SSL validation.  Don't do this in production.... Just debugging!!

   Like Postman, in `Settings->General->SSL certificate verification->set Off`
2. Your function to get HttpPost parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute, like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public Server Add([FromBody] Server server)
{
    return server;
}
```